# Error cs0246 "The type or namespace name 'Player' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using unity to create a top-down 2d game and I keep getting the error Error cs0246  "The type or namespace name 'Player' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) It seems like I have looked everywhere but I can't fix it as I am new to unity. This is the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour{

        public int playerId = 0;
        public Animator animator;
        public GameObject crosshair7;   

        private Player player;

        void Awake() {
            player = ReInput.players.GetPlayer(playerId);
        }

        void Update()
        {

            Vector3 movement = newVector3(Input.GetAxis("MoveHorizontal"),Input.GetAxis("MoveVertical"), 0.0f);

            if(player.GetButton("Fire")) {
                 Debug.Log("Fire");
            }

            Movecrosshair7();

            animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", movement.x);
            animator.SetFloat("Vertical", movement.y);
            animator.SetFloat("Magnitude", movement.magnitude);

            transform.position = transform.position + movement * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        private void Movecrosshair7() {
            Vector3 aim = new Vector3(player.GetAxis("AimHorizontal"), player.GetAxis("AimVertical"), 0.0f);

            if (aim.magnitude > 0.0f) {
                aim.Normalize();
                aim *= 0.04f;
                crosshair7.transform.localPosition = aim;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error is because you've created a class called `Player` in another namespace, and haven't imported it. If you're using Visual Studio you can do `ctrl+.` on the red underlined `private Player;` to automatically import it, otherwise add your namespace to the top of the file:

```
using My.Players.Namespace;
```

---

I noticed another error in your code:

```
Vector3 movement = newVector3(Input.GetAxis("MoveHorizontal"),Input.GetAxis("MoveVertical"), 0.0f);
```

should be

```
Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("MoveHorizontal"), Input.GetAxis("MoveVertical"), 0.0f);
```